# SUM CASE WHEN (SQL)

Tags: sql, db-browser-sqlite

I want to apply a simple SUM CASE WHEN to a table I have created from CSV (in DB Browser for SQLite). At the moment I have the below code:

```
Select user_id,
CASE Overall_Result
WHEN 'Fail' then 0 
WHEN 'Pass' then 1 else 0
END as "Case When"
from NewTable
```

This code gives me:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGPu2.png)

However, now I want to amend the above code so that it SUMS the values in the created CASE WHEN column for every particular user_id. As you can see in e.g. row 1 and 2 of the image, we have the same user_id and the corresponding values in the second column. I want to combine these user_id's so there is just one instance of each in column 1 and then have the SUM of all the corresponding values for this user_id in the second column. GROUP BY doesn't seem to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select user_id,
       SUM(CASE Overall_Result WHEN 'Fail' then 0 WHEN 'Pass' then 1 else 0
           END) as sum_value
from NewTable
group by user_id;
```

Or, if you just want the number of passes, you can use the shorthand:

```
SUM(Overall_Result = 'Pass')
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the sum()  and the related  group by eg:

```
    Select user_id,
    sum( CASE Overall_Result
    WHEN 'Fail' then 0 
    WHEN 'Pass' then 1 else 0
    END )  as "Case When"
    from NewTable
    group  by user_id
```